# Pass same value to different text in drop down WFFM SItecore

Tags: wffm

I want to pass same value for different text items in drop down. But drop down "value" field is only accepting unique values. 
When I open Data source field of WFFM sitecore "drop list" item and give the source of items. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior, value should be *unique* for `DDL`.

You can create custom `DDL` and keep `DDL's` items inside page content as `datasource`.

[image]

In below screenshot choose `Sitecore items`. Here each item has `key`, `value` fields. We can set same value for `key` field for multiple items. This will be fulfill your requirement.

[image]